# Fit height of div to screen height and fix footer to bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a site where when there isn't enough content the footer moves up and doesn't stick to the bottom. Im trying to figure out how to make the div between the footer and the header stretch to the available space in order for the footer to remain at the bottom and not look like this:

[image]

I've tried setting my heights to 100% it but does not work.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="body_div">
        <section id="main_section">
        </section>
        <aside id="sidebar">                    
        </aside>
    </div>
    <footer id="footer">
        &copy; Copyright  by SimKessy
    </footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    width: 100%; /*always specify this when using flexBox*/ 
    height:100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-pack:center; /*way of centering the website*/
    -moz-box-pack:center;
    box-pack:center;
    background:url('images/bg/bg9.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#wrapper{
    max-width: 850px;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box; /*means this is a box with children inside*/
    -moz-box-orient:vertical;
    -moz-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; /*allows site to grow or shrink 1 = flex 0 = statix*/
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    height:100%;    
    z-index: 1;
}
#body_div{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    color:#000000;
    margin-top: 190px;
    height: 100%;
}
#main_section{
   /* border:1px solid blue;*/
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; 
    -moz-box-flex:1;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is my site http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/video.html
You can see what I mean when you go to widescreen mode using the side menu.

Comment: Google sticky footer, it shows how to make your website's footer stick to the bottom of the page.

Comment: hey, sorry the solutions kinda made things worst.

Comment: Ah. I can edit my solution if there are still issues. Could elaborate more on what the issues were with the solutions below? I would be glad to add some new fixes if necessary.

Comment: Yea sure, this is my site right now: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/ When you go to the side menu and make it wide screen (see trailers page) you can see how everything moves up (like in the picture). I was hoping for something that wouldn't adjust the height of the body.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're actually really close to the answer. However, you cannot simply set only the `#wrapper` div to 100% height. You should include this line:

```
html, body, #wrapper {
width:100%; 
height:100%;
}
```

Currently, the issue is that the `wrapper` div has no clue what is 100%. It needs a parent with a defined height, which comes from the `html` and `body` elements.

As for the sticky footer, just use absolute positioning and set `bottom:0px;`. Don't use a 3rd party API for this; using `position:absolute` is a ridiculously easy fix, and adding a 3rd party API will just slow down your site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery to calculate the needed height:

- set the margin to 0 for body
- then use the following script:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        $('#wrapperHeight').height(clientHeight+'px');
        var bodyHeight = clientHeight - $('#body_div').css("marginTop").replace('px', '') - $('#footer').outerHeight(true);
        $('#body_div').height(bodyHeight+'px');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You could do this...but it's much more complicated than the CSS. Why use JavaScript when it's in-built with CSS?