# Fit div to screen

Tags: html, css, scroll, height

I have two divs:

```
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="scroll">
</div>
```

"header" is a fixed size (40px) bar, and "scroll" is a sidebar, with a scrollbar. I want to make "scroll" fill all the height that is available,  between "header" and the bottom of screen. But if I set 100% or 100vh height on "scroll", it fills the height, but also takes 40px more, which doesn't fit in the screen, so the scrollbar appears on the browser too, even though the div "scroll" has it's own scrollbar.

Comment: `width: calc(100% - 40px);`? (Is CSS3 though)

Comment: Try this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15454401/2174170)

Comment: putvandes method worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you could use CSS3 [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

```
width: calc(100% - 40px);
```

But beware that not all browsers support this (yet).
See http://caniuse.com/calc to see browser support for `calc`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways.

```
div {
width: calc (100% - 40px);
}
```

or

```
div {
margin: 40px 0 0 40px;
}
```

this will margin the top and the left side. assuming thats where the scroll bars are. If you want to just margin the top 40 pix then do

```
div {
    margin-top: 40px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give the `.scroll` element `position:absolute;` like this: <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/9aBwb/1/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="scroll"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    background-color:yellow;
    position:relative;
    height:500px;
}
.header {
    background-color:red;
    height:40px;
}
.scroll {
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```